# how to disable automatic brightness adjust Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, brightness

How to disable automatic disable brightness adjust in Ubuntu 18.04. I only found the solution for Ubuntu 16 or below which just turn it off in settings. But In Ubuntu 18.04 I can't found and settings about it.

Comment: What laptop make and model do you have?

Comment: I had the same problem, but it was caused by a BIOS setup setting.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings → *Power* → turn off *Dim screen when inactive*.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: There is no Automatic brightness setting in ubuntu 18.04 like what I said in the topic

Comment: Not that one. That one is just dimming the display but my problem is it automatically adjusts brightness, both increase and decrease.

Answer (score 0):

Generally in Linux (my distro is Parrot OS), you can go to Settings → *Power Management Preferences* → if it is a laptop choose *On AC/Battery Power* tabs (even some desktop PCs have these settings) → disable *Reduce Backlight Brightness*, if it's enabled, AND set a higher value for reduce screen brightness when idle (for at least 5 mins).